# Using variables/objects across methods - Java

Tags: java, variables, object, methods

So, in the following code I am trying to let the objects "reader" and "writer" be recognized by some of my methods, so I later will be able to run them at the same time (I'm thinking like using threads). So that's basically my question, is there a way I can get the "reader" and "writer" objects to be recognized in my other methods?

```js
package com.Kaelinator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class ServerManager2 {

  static boolean Running = false;
  //static String command = "C:/Users/Kael/Desktop/minecraftserver/RUN.bat";
  static String command = "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/rekt/Run.bat";
  static String shutDown = "C:/Windows/System32/shutdown.exe -r -t 0";



  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    runServer();
    while (Running) {
      chatChecker();
    }

    Commands();

  }




  public static void chatChecker() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int hour = now.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = now.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
    int second = now.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

    String hourSyntax = Integer.toString(hour);
    String minuteSyntax = Integer.toString(minute);
    String secondSyntax = Integer.toString(second);

    String chatChecker = "[" + hourSyntax + ":" + minuteSyntax + ":" + secondSyntax +
      "] [Server thread/INFO]: ";
    System.out.println(chatChecker);
  }

  public static void sleepThread(long time) {

    try {
      Thread.sleep(time * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }


  public static void runServer() throws IOException {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
    process.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  }

  public static void readOutput() {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }

  public static void Commands() throws IOException {

    Running = true;

    try {

      sleepThread(3);
      writer.append("say SERVER STARTED");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(14100);
      writer.append("say restarting in 5 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 4 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 3 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 2 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 1 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(30);
      writer.append("say restarting in 30 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(20);
      writer.append("say restarting in 10 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(5);
      writer.append("say restarting in 5 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 4 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 3 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 2 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 1 second");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      writer.append("stop");
      writer.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make them global variables?

Comment: xD how do I do that? Don't put them in a method? @brso05

Comment: @brso05, what does *global variables* mean?

Comment: Yeah I'm not too keen on what those are either @brso05

Comment: ... how do I do that? @Compass

Comment: Move the code from your main method into your runServer() method. Then, simply make the reader and writer parameters to your subsequent methods and pass them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not a recommended Object Oriented practice, one way to do what you want would be to set `reader` and `writer` as `static` fields, just like your `Running` field.

EDIT:

The following code compiles and runs. I added two static fields and added a missing `throws` on a method.

```
package com.Kaelinator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class ServerManager2 {

  static BufferedWriter writer;
  static BufferedReader reader;
  static boolean Running = false;
  //static String command = "C:/Users/Kael/Desktop/minecraftserver/RUN.bat";
  static String command = "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/rekt/Run.bat";
  static String shutDown = "C:/Windows/System32/shutdown.exe -r -t 0";



  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    runServer();
    while (Running) {
      chatChecker();
    }

    Commands();

  }




  public static void chatChecker() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int hour = now.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = now.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
    int second = now.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

    String hourSyntax = Integer.toString(hour);
    String minuteSyntax = Integer.toString(minute);
    String secondSyntax = Integer.toString(second);

    String chatChecker = "[" + hourSyntax + ":" + minuteSyntax + ":" + secondSyntax +
            "] [Server thread/INFO]: ";
    System.out.println(chatChecker);
  }

  public static void sleepThread(long time) {

    try {
      Thread.sleep(time * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }


  public static void runServer() throws IOException {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
    process.getInputStream();

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  }

  public static void readOutput() throws IOException {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }

  public static void Commands() throws IOException {

    Running = true;

    try {

      sleepThread(3);
      writer.append("say SERVER STARTED");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(14100);
      writer.append("say restarting in 5 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 4 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 3 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 2 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(60);
      writer.append("say restarting in 1 minutes");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(30);
      writer.append("say restarting in 30 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(20);
      writer.append("say restarting in 10 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(5);
      writer.append("say restarting in 5 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 4 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 3 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 2 seconds");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      sleepThread(1);
      writer.append("say restarting in 1 second");
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      writer.append("stop");
      writer.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This throws me an error: "Remove invalid modifiers" :/ I'm not sure if that's just because it's in a method or not...

Comment: @Kaelinator Without a concrete example I can't tell you what you did wrong. I've added a full example to my answer. This code compiles and runs.

Comment: Glad I could help! If programming is something that you'd like to pursue and get better at, I would recommend reading on Object Oriented Programming best practices. Setting everything to static is fine for a short proof of concept but it won't scale to medium/large projects :) Happy coding!